# How to improve F1 score for classification

Tags: python, performance, classification, grid-search, ensemble-learning

I'm working on predicting if any task breaches a given deadline or not(Binary Classification Problem)

I've used Logistic Regression, Random Forest and XGBoost. All of them give an F1 score of around 56% for the class label 1(i.e the F1 score of the positive class only).

I've used:

- StandardScaler()
- GridSearchCV for Hyperparameter Tuning
- Recursive Feature Elimination(for feature selection)
- SMOTE(the dataset is imbalanced so I used SMOTE to create new examples from existing examples)

to try and improve the F score of this model.

I've also created an ensemble model using `EnsembleVoteClassifier`.As you can see from the picture, the weighted F score is 94% however the F score for class 1 (i.e positive class which says that the task will cross the deadline) is just 57%.
[image]

After applying all those methods mentioned above, I have been able to improve the f1 score of label 1 from 6% to 57%. However, I'm not sure what else to do to further improve the F score of the label 1.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the fact that you have a relatively small number of True 1s samples in you datasets affects the performance of your classifier.

You have an "imbalanced data", you have much more of the 0s samples than of 1s.

There are multiple way to deal with imbalanced data. Each learner you have applied have its own "trick" for it.  However, a general thing you can try is to resample the 1s samples. That is, artificially increase the proportion of the 1s in your dataset.

You can read more about different options here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/methods-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-data-5b761be45a18

Comment: Hi! I've used SMOTE to add new examples:

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=27)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)

Comment: Is the number above 287 is after the resampling ?

Comment: Yes, the count for class 0 and 1 are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You should also experiment with Under-Sampling. In general, you won't get much improvement by simply changing the algorithm. You should look into more advanced ensemble based techniques specifically designed for dealing with class imbalance.

You can also try out the approach used in this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0031320312001471

Alternatively, you could look into more advanced data synthesis methods.

Comment: I tried undersampling the majority class but the f1 score reduced to 0.41 for the label 1.